# Powerpivot Graph 'Region' Total Sales vs 'Employee' Total sales in a period of time

Tags: sql-server, excel, mdx, powerpivot, dax

I want to create a column chart that will show: Total Sales, total revenue for a selected employee vs. total sales, total revenue of his Region. I mean, one employee belongs to one Region ... And I want to obtain the sales amount, revenue amount of the employee and compare it with the sales amount, revenue amount of his region in a period of time. Like this:

```
 Employee A   Region A    Employee A   Region A
  Sales        Sales        Revenue     Revenue
  10K           50K           2K          10K

_________________________________________________

         **Sales**                   **Revenue**
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to assume some things since you didn't share anything about your data model.  I'm going to assume that you have a single fact table that has a relationship to both employee and sales territory (which contains region).  I'm going to assume that this fact table has both sales and revenue in it.  You can either post more info about your data model and I can update my answer or you can switch out the table and measure names to make it work.

I would guess that you already have a measure that is sales and a measure that is revenue.  They probably look like this:

```
Revenue:= Sum('Fact table' [Revenue Amount]) 
Sales:= Sum('Fact table' [Sales Amount])
```

You can use the above for your employee-level amounts.

Then you need the amount for the region. I used the ALLEXCEPT to remove the other filters (like employee) to get the region totals.

```
Region Revenue := Calculate(Sum('Fact table'[Revenue Amount]), 
                           ALLEXCEPT( Sales Territory, 'Sales Territory'[Region]))
Region Sales := Calculate(Sum('Fact table'[Sales Amount]), 
                           ALLEXCEPT( Sales Territory, 'Sales Territory'[Region]))
```

Here's [a good article](http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/ratio-over-subtotals-with-normalized-tables-in-dax) that talks about getting those totals and creating ratios with them.